# get java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out when running vision sample code

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

My project has a OCR requirement and I want to use the google cloud Vision API. I download the sample code via GIT, but it report follow errors:

> Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect
>   timed out     at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)   at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)    at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:668)    at
>   sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.(HttpsClient.java:264)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1138)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1032)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1316)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1291)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:77)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:981)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:283)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:384)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.intercept(Credential.java:217)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:868)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
>     at
>   com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.vision.samples.label.LabelApp.labelImage(LabelApp.java:136)
>     at
>   com.google.cloud.vision.samples.label.LabelApp.main(LabelApp.java:71)

I don`t modify any code and I could get the successfully test results on the API browser explorer. Has anyone met this kind of issue before?Could you please give me any suggestion?

Comment: I test the demo from China, is it possible because of the network restriction? I already setup a VPN connect and I could access the Vision API explorer test page and perform the testing. Can anyone give me any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

`java.net.SocketTimeoutException` means the connection timed out before a response was received from the remote host. This is almost always caused by local network issues, or proxy or firewall configurations.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by setting proxy mode to global mode

Comment: can you provide more information please? what proxy mode?